# Stored procedure is returning multiple result sets - how to handle in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure that is returning two result sets.

I have written the code, but don't know the way how to store two tables record.

```
string sql = @"EXEC SP_CreateHosts 
                            @HostId,
                            @ConfigId,
                            @HostGivenName,
                            @HostEmailAddress,
                            @SurName,
                            @DisplayName,
                            @HostIsActive";

List<SqlParameter> parms = new List<SqlParameter>
        {
            // Create parameter(s)    
            new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@HostId", Value = obj.HostId },
            new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@ConfigId", Value = obj.ConfigId },
            new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@HostGivenName", Value = obj.HostGivenName },
            new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@HostEmailAddress", Value = obj.HostEmailAddress },
            new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@SurName", Value = obj.SurName },
            new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@DisplayName", Value = obj.DisplayName },
            new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@HostIsActive", Value = obj.HostIsActive }

        };

data = context.OhslotsMasters.FromSqlRaw<OhslotsMaster>(sql, parms.ToArray()).ToList();
```

This code is storing only one record, I need to store the other record as well.

Comment: Side note if you're using SQL Server: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: This question is seriously confused. You say your sproc returns data, then you say it stores data, then you say it only stores one out of two records, but you only load one set of data into the params (so it's not really surprising).. are you expecting that creating a sql parameter and setting its value somehow magically makes the parameter aware of the property the data came from so that you could execute it against a list of objects and each one of them would be uploaded? (It doesn't work that way with Value.. maybe with SourceColumn, but not like this..)

Comment: I think this would help you: [Stored Procedures with Multiple Result Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/advanced/multiple-result-sets#:~:text=Sometimes%20when%20using%20stored%20procedures%20you%20will%20need,first%20result%20set%20to%20the%20calling%20code.%20)